# Why would jQuery detach improve efficiency?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a ajax result handler:

```
$('.update-flight-status').on('click', function() {
  $.getJSON('/status', function(result) {
    var statusElements = $.map(result, function(status, index) {
      var listItem = $('<li></li>');
      $('<h3>'+status.name+'</h3>').appendTo(listItem);
      $('<p>'+status.status+'</p>').appendTo(listItem);
      return listItem;
    });
$('.status-list').html(statusElements); });
```

￼AND

```
$('.update-flight-status').on('click', function() {
  $.getJSON('/status', function(result) {
    var statusElements = $.map(result, function(status, index) {
      var listItem = $('<li></li>');
      $('<h3>'+status.name+'</h3>').appendTo(listItem);
      $('<p>'+status.status+'</p>').appendTo(listItem);
      return listItem;
    });
    $('.status-list').detach()
                  .html(statusElements)
                  .appendTo('.status');
  });
});
```

Why would the second example, where "detach" is used, is more efficient than the first one?

Comment: @FelixKling I was doing a tutorial from codeschool.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery `detach` is the same as `remove`, only that it keeps jquery-specific assignments to that node, via `data`, or event handlers. This method comes in handy when you plan to re-attach the node to another point in the DOM.

In the first version you really can't tell if `status-list` is child of `status`, but in any case, **you are NOT removing the node**, so stuff like datas,  event handlers, assigned classes, etc... DO remain.

In the second version, you remove `status-list` from the DOM, then modify it, then re-attach. I assume on the same place (but there's missing code, it's just a wild guess) I'd say it's in fact **SLOWER** than the first case, because the first case just modifies the HTML contents without bothering to detach/reattach anything.

The case where `detach` would improve efficiency is if you remove that node, and it has been heavily customized, with added classes, data, etc... then reattach it **elsewhere**, *versus removing the node, recreating it, reassign all stuff, etc etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Detach is only useful and efficient when you specifically need to move an elements location, or prevent a 1000 items to be rendered when only one at a time can be seen.

Your example does not make detach look efficient, it looks as if the element has been positioned incorrectly from the start.